# How do I create a swap partition using parted?

Tags: parted

How do I create a swap partition using command line `gparted`? `(parted)`

I've managed to create a partition but I can't seem to set the partition to `Linux swap / Solaris`.
I've tried

```
mkpart extended linux-swap -512MB -1s
// -> Error: Invalid number.
&

mkpart extended linux-swap(v1) -512MB -1s
// -> Error: Invalid number.
&

mkpart
type:   extended
Start:  -512MB
End:    -1s
// this works, but I can't set the FS-TYPE
```

// help page

```
(parted) help mkpart                                                      
  mkpart PART-TYPE [FS-TYPE] START END     make a partition

    PART-TYPE is one of: primary, logical, extended
        FS-TYPE is one of: zfs, btrfs, nilfs2, ext4, ext3, ext2, fat32, fat16, hfsx, hfs+, hfs, jfs, swsusp, linux-swap(v1), linux-swap(v0), ntfs,
        reiserfs, freebsd-ufs, hp-ufs, sun-ufs, xfs, apfs2, apfs1, asfs, amufs5, amufs4, amufs3, amufs2, amufs1, amufs0, amufs, affs7, affs6, affs5,
        affs4, affs3, affs2, affs1, affs0, linux-swap, linux-swap(new), linux-swap(old)
        START and END are disk locations, such as 4GB or 10%.  Negative values count from the end of the disk.  For example, -1s specifies exactly the
        last sector.

        'mkpart' makes a partition without creating a new file system on the partition.  FS-TYPE may be specified to set an appropriate partition ID.
```

Comment: Create a partition without a filesystem and run `mkswap` is the simplest way.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you use `parted` on the `/dev/sda` disk device and you have created the primary ext4 partition on `/dev/sda2`

```
$ sudo parted /dev/sda
(parted) mkpart
Partition type? primary/extended? primary
File system type? [ext2]? linux-swap
Start? 0%
End? 100%
```

Then you need to format the swap filesystem and turn it on

```
$ sudo mkswap /dev/vdb2
$ sudo swapon --all --verbose
swapon on /dev/sda2
swapon: /dev/sda2: found swap signature: version 1, page-size 4, same byte order
swapon: /dev/sda2: pagesize=4096, swapsize=2147483648, devsize=2147483648
```

Add it to `/etc/fstab` so that it will be mounted on every reboot.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/fstab
/dev/sda2 none swap sw 0 0
```

[Ubuntu's guide on Swap is pretty comprehensive](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq).

Answer (score -1):

If you already have the partition created,  I think you can use "mkswap" instead of "mkpart".